# Are async and await supported natively?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have noticed that async and await are used a lot.

So I want to know if I can use them without using Babel or something else: can I use async & await without adding anything in my code?

Comment: Why don't you try ? is it so hard to try ?

Comment: The only things that matter is which platform/version you target. If the platforms you target has it then by all means.

Comment: This sort of question is what [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com) is for

Comment: For node.js, `async` and `await` have been built in for quite awhile (since version 8 or version 7.6 with a command line flag) and you can use them natively just fine.  Here's a [good Javascript feature compatibility chart](https://node.green/) for different versions of node.js.

Comment: @jfriend00 The command line flag was only used in 7.0 through 7.5 . node.js 7.6 has async/await support with no flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v8 has had support for async/await [since version 5.5](https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-55#language-features), which node.js uses in [version 7.6](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V7.md#2017-02-21-version-760-current-italoacasas) (released in February 2017). All versions of node.js since 7.6 also have built in support for async/await.

Node v6 (LTS) and v7 [are no longer supported](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/), thus all supported versions of node.js have async/await built in. If your version of node.js does not support async/await you need to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

As covered on [node.green](https://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions), Node.js supports async & await natively since **7.6.0**.

So if your setup (and server) are running a matching or newer version, you're good to go.